# How to get Grafana's Mysql Exporter Dashboard to pull data?

Tags: prometheus, grafana-dashboard

Running Ubuntu 23.04. It came with the ability to install the prometheus-mysqld-exporter apt package. Went ahead and installed it, enabled it and started it.

The url at http://192.168.0.5:9104/metrics responds with this:

```
# HELP go_gc_duration_seconds A summary of the pause duration of garbage collection cycles.
# TYPE go_gc_duration_seconds summary
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0"} 9.1359e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.25"} 0.000102738
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.5"} 0.000134885
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.75"} 0.000168224
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="1"} 0.000181078
go_gc_duration_seconds_sum 0.002018707
go_gc_duration_seconds_count 15
# HELP go_goroutines Number of goroutines that currently exist.
# TYPE go_goroutines gauge
go_goroutines 9
# HELP go_info Information about the Go environment.
# TYPE go_info gauge
go_info{version="go1.19.4"} 1
# HELP go_memstats_alloc_bytes Number of bytes allocated and still in use.
# TYPE go_memstats_alloc_bytes gauge
go_memstats_alloc_bytes 3.135808e+06
# HELP go_memstats_alloc_bytes_total Total number of bytes allocated, even if freed.
# TYPE go_memstats_alloc_bytes_total counter
go_memstats_alloc_bytes_total 2.3260592e+07
# HELP go_memstats_buck_hash_sys_bytes Number of bytes used by the profiling bucket hash table.
# TYPE go_memstats_buck_hash_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_buck_hash_sys_bytes 4617
# HELP go_memstats_frees_total Total number of frees.
# TYPE go_memstats_frees_total counter
go_memstats_frees_total 35802
# HELP go_memstats_gc_sys_bytes Number of bytes used for garbage collection system metadata.
# TYPE go_memstats_gc_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_gc_sys_bytes 8.930752e+06
# HELP go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes Number of heap bytes allocated and still in use.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes 3.135808e+06
# HELP go_memstats_heap_idle_bytes Number of heap bytes waiting to be used.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_idle_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_idle_bytes 3.260416e+06
# HELP go_memstats_heap_inuse_bytes Number of heap bytes that are in use.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_inuse_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_inuse_bytes 4.603904e+06
# HELP go_memstats_heap_objects Number of allocated objects.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_objects gauge
go_memstats_heap_objects 3257
# HELP go_memstats_heap_released_bytes Number of heap bytes released to OS.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_released_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_released_bytes 2.8672e+06
# HELP go_memstats_heap_sys_bytes Number of heap bytes obtained from system.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_sys_bytes 7.86432e+06
# HELP go_memstats_last_gc_time_seconds Number of seconds since 1970 of last garbage collection.
# TYPE go_memstats_last_gc_time_seconds gauge
go_memstats_last_gc_time_seconds 1.6834325351535332e+09
# HELP go_memstats_lookups_total Total number of pointer lookups.
# TYPE go_memstats_lookups_total counter
go_memstats_lookups_total 0
# HELP go_memstats_mallocs_total Total number of mallocs.
# TYPE go_memstats_mallocs_total counter
go_memstats_mallocs_total 39059
# HELP go_memstats_mcache_inuse_bytes Number of bytes in use by mcache structures.
# TYPE go_memstats_mcache_inuse_bytes gauge
go_memstats_mcache_inuse_bytes 4800
# HELP go_memstats_mcache_sys_bytes Number of bytes used for mcache structures obtained from system.
# TYPE go_memstats_mcache_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_mcache_sys_bytes 15600
# HELP go_memstats_mspan_inuse_bytes Number of bytes in use by mspan structures.
# TYPE go_memstats_mspan_inuse_bytes gauge
go_memstats_mspan_inuse_bytes 76752
# HELP go_memstats_mspan_sys_bytes Number of bytes used for mspan structures obtained from system.
# TYPE go_memstats_mspan_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_mspan_sys_bytes 81360
# HELP go_memstats_next_gc_bytes Number of heap bytes when next garbage collection will take place.
# TYPE go_memstats_next_gc_bytes gauge
go_memstats_next_gc_bytes 4.903744e+06
# HELP go_memstats_other_sys_bytes Number of bytes used for other system allocations.
# TYPE go_memstats_other_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_other_sys_bytes 911751
# HELP go_memstats_stack_inuse_bytes Number of bytes in use by the stack allocator.
# TYPE go_memstats_stack_inuse_bytes gauge
go_memstats_stack_inuse_bytes 524288
# HELP go_memstats_stack_sys_bytes Number of bytes obtained from system for stack allocator.
# TYPE go_memstats_stack_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_stack_sys_bytes 524288
# HELP go_memstats_sys_bytes Number of bytes obtained from system.
# TYPE go_memstats_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_sys_bytes 1.8332688e+07
# HELP go_threads Number of OS threads created.
# TYPE go_threads gauge
go_threads 8
# HELP mysql_exporter_last_scrape_error Whether the last scrape of metrics from MySQL resulted in an error (1 for error, 0 for success).
# TYPE mysql_exporter_last_scrape_error gauge
mysql_exporter_last_scrape_error 1
# HELP mysql_exporter_scrapes_total Total number of times MySQL was scraped for metrics.
# TYPE mysql_exporter_scrapes_total counter
mysql_exporter_scrapes_total 30
# HELP mysql_up Whether the MySQL server is up.
# TYPE mysql_up gauge
mysql_up 0
# HELP mysqld_exporter_build_info A metric with a constant '1' value labeled by version, revision, branch, goversion from which mysqld_exporter was built, and the goos and goarch for the build.
# TYPE mysqld_exporter_build_info gauge
mysqld_exporter_build_info{branch="debian/sid",goarch="amd64",goos="linux",goversion="go1.19.4",revision="0.14.0-3",version="0.14.0"} 1
# HELP process_cpu_seconds_total Total user and system CPU time spent in seconds.
# TYPE process_cpu_seconds_total counter
process_cpu_seconds_total 0.45
# HELP process_max_fds Maximum number of open file descriptors.
# TYPE process_max_fds gauge
process_max_fds 524288
# HELP process_open_fds Number of open file descriptors.
# TYPE process_open_fds gauge
process_open_fds 10
# HELP process_resident_memory_bytes Resident memory size in bytes.
# TYPE process_resident_memory_bytes gauge
process_resident_memory_bytes 1.773568e+07
# HELP process_start_time_seconds Start time of the process since unix epoch in seconds.
# TYPE process_start_time_seconds gauge
process_start_time_seconds 1.6834321218e+09
# HELP process_virtual_memory_bytes Virtual memory size in bytes.
# TYPE process_virtual_memory_bytes gauge
process_virtual_memory_bytes 1.194979328e+09
# HELP process_virtual_memory_max_bytes Maximum amount of virtual memory available in bytes.
# TYPE process_virtual_memory_max_bytes gauge
process_virtual_memory_max_bytes 1.8446744073709552e+19
# HELP promhttp_metric_handler_requests_in_flight Current number of scrapes being served.
# TYPE promhttp_metric_handler_requests_in_flight gauge
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_in_flight 1
# HELP promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total Total number of scrapes by HTTP status code.
# TYPE promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total counter
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{code="200"} 29
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{code="500"} 0
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{code="503"} 0
```

The data seems to be there. However when I installed the Grafana Mysql Dashboard and it's recording rules recommended on this page: https://grafana.com/oss/prometheus/exporters/mysql-exporter/?tab=dashboards

Is the exporter on this page different than the one packaged with Ubuntu? My understanding is that they are the same.

There is no data present in those dashboards. Has anyone encountered this issue?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer on this thread https://groups.google.com/g/prometheus-users/c/BGPGd9sV0fM

The mysql_exporter_last_scrape_error 1 statement and the thread above made me recheck my mysql credentials. There was a typo. That fixed my issue.